# Why does margins apply differently to inline-block and block elements in CSS?

Tags: html, css

The problem:

An element with `display: inline-block;` will have a different margin than an element with `display: block;` even if the margin is set to for instance `margin-top: 30px;` for both!

The margin-top will apply for the element with inline-block, but not precisely the same as for an element with block. There will be some pixels in difference. Why?

Comment: On which browsers are you testing?

Comment: Not a direct answer, but this article may shed some light: http://robertnyman.com/2010/02/24/css-display-inline-block-why-it-rocks-and-why-it-sucks/

Comment: Please provide more details, such as a minimal document where the problem can be observed. The problem cannot be observed in a simple test, and it probably relates to something else on the page. (What looks like a margin might be something else.)

Comment: You're right Yukka. I got the answer from Hexxagonal below before I had the chance to post more details. It was in fact due to the header element above (and me not knowing of collapsing margins). Thanks for pointing it out though.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think what you're referring to is the fact that margins of inline-block elements do not collapse, but on block elements they do collapse.  [The Box model page goes over this really well](http://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=inline%20block%20margin%20collapsing&source=web&cd=1&ved=0CCAQFjAA&url=http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/box.html&ei=g10ET523NM7iggef9-mPAg&usg=AFQjCNGVoa_ZICKwW3I8ol2HokNYEafeoA).

So what is a collapsing margin? Say you have an element with 10px margin on the bottom followed by an element with 5px margin on the top.  The margin between the two will not be 15, but will collapse down to the largest of the two (10px).

Comment: Thank you! This was indeed the answer, as I had a header element above which had a `margin-bottom: 0.5em;`. When I removed that, the element below aligned perfectly, when being either set to `inline-block` or `block`.

Comment: Your welcome. As soon as I read top margin, I figured that was it.

Answer (score 1):

Inline-blocks have by default a padding between them, (the size of a space, so 1em in width) if the element tags are not placed next to eachother without space:

```
<element></element><element></element>
```

Will be okay, but the following will not:

```
<element></element>
<element></element>
```

Blocks do not have this issue, that's why it seems different. It adds the default to the padding with the inline.

To overcome this, you can set the **parent** `font-size` to 0, or subtract the extra padding width from your desired width.

Comment: It can't be this because `margin-top` is mentioned in the question.